# BeagleBone to Arduino analog communication

Tags: arduino, beagle-bone

- I have a BeagleBone Black, an Arduino Duemilanove and a WS2812b LED strip driven with 5 V.
- I have no level shifters, nor I intend to order one.
- The Arduino works perfectly with a LED strip, and I need the BeagleBone Black just to send simple commands like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... to make the Arduino perform one of five modes.
- The BeagleBone Black's USB port is taken by other device that I need, and I do not intend to use USB splitters.

What is the best way to communicate between the BeagleBone Black and the Arduino in this situation? If I do not want to use level shifter I2C and RS232 TTL communication is impossible?

Is it OK to use for example just one wire (plus ground) and communicate via the analog port using `analogWrite()` on the BeagleBone Black and `analogRead()` on the Arduino, and is there some additional advice on communicating this way?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* MetNP, but I'm afraid that questions like this are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to make pseudo logic lines over analog between the BBB and the arduino using analog signals. The only real downside is that it will be slower and you have to write more code. Just be sure that you keep in mind the analog pins on the BBB only accept 1.8v so don't put anything beyond that on it.

Answer (score 0):

BeagleBone black has 6 UART ports - you can connect one of them to the Arduino digital pins and use software serial on the Arduino. See:

- [Using the BeagleBone‎ > ‎Serial ports / UART](http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/serial-ports-uart)
- [SoftwareSerial Library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial)

Comment: do I need aditional hw for this like level shifter from BeagleBone's 3.3v to arduino's 5v ?

Comment: @MetNP no problem. I am still using it.